# Is there a way to make PhotosPicker in SwiftUI use the camera instead?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, photosui

Is there a way to make the PhotosUI PhotosPicker in SwiftUI source the photos directly from the Camera? I'm trying to change the PhotosPickers in my app to use the camera instead of forcing the user to select images from their image library. Is there a way to dictate the source of PhotosPicker images like you can with ImagePicker?

I did an online search and a lot of articles talked about PhotoPicker, but none of the examples had a way to make it use the camera. Should I just bite the bullet and switch everything to image picker or is there a way to make PhotoPicker use the camera?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to use camera in PhotoPicker. I searched a lot about this and came to conclusion to use ImagePicker instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1 : Create a dialogue to select the option for a camera of the photo

step 2 : Create a action sheet for for image picker

```
struct BaseView: View {
     @State var showSelection: Bool = false
     @State var showPicker: Bool = false
     @State var type: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .photoLibrary

      var body: some View {

            Zstack {
                YourView()
            }
            .confirmationDialog(Lables.selectImage,
                            isPresented: $showSelection,
                            titleVisibility: .hidden) {
            
            Button(ButtonName.camera) {
                showPicker = true
                type = .camera
            }
            
            Button(ButtonName.photos) {
                showPicker = true
                type = .photoLibrary
             
            }
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showPicker) {
            ImagePickerView(sourceType: profileImageVM.pickerType) { image in
                 // image your image
            }
        }

      }
}
```

step 3: Create Image Picker

```
struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    private var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    public init(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
    }
    
    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = self.sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}
    
    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(
            onDismiss: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() },
            onImagePicked: self.onImagePicked
        )
    }
    
    final public class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        
        private let onDismiss: () -> Void
        private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void
        
        init(onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
            self.onDismiss = onDismiss
            self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
        }
        
        public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                          didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.onImagePicked(image)
            }
            self.onDismiss()
        }
        public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was specifically asking for PhotosPicker in SwiftUI. This solution is viable, but you should absolutely preface by explaining that it isn't possible natively.

Comment: thanks, man will take care for this.